# CURL: Maintain session without redirect

Tags: php, session, curl

It feels like it might be a dumb question, but after a while searching of possibilities and playing around with values, I still can't seem to figure out how to do this.

What I'm basicly trying to do is to obtain account information from Rockstar Games Social Club. I found out that this site makes use of an private API. But in order to make it work, it requires an active session with the server.

Without authentication the API returns:

```
{"Portfolio":[{"CharacterName":"Michael","TotalShares":0,"TotalInvested":"$0","DayRange":"N/A","ChangePercent":"N/A","ChangeDollar":"N/A","ChangeDirection":"","Investments":[]},{"CharacterName":"Franklin","TotalShares":0,"TotalInvested":"$0","DayRange":"N/A","ChangePercent":"N/A","ChangeDollar":"N/A","ChangeDirection":"","Investments":[]},{"CharacterName":"Trevor","TotalShares":0,"TotalInvested":"$0","DayRange":"N/A","ChangePercent":"N/A","ChangeDollar":"N/A","ChangeDirection":"","Investments":[]}]}
```

So, I'm trying to find a way to make this work. And I it seems that cURL would be the best way to do this.

However, the code I've tested, is redirecting me to their website, instead of getting data after which I can call a new request in hope it would work.

My PHP Code:

```
class DownloadJSON {
    public function download($url) {
        return file_get_contents($url);
    }

    public function login($url, $username, $password) {
        $url = "https://socialclub.rockstargames.com/profile/signin";
        $vars = "login-field=". $username ."&password-field=". $password . "&rememberme-field=off";

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        $me = $this->download($url);

        curl_close($ch);

        echo $me;
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
    if (strlen($_GET['url']) > 0) {
        if ($_GET['action'] == "stocks") {
            $downloadJSON = new DownloadJSON();
            echo $downloadJSON->download($_GET['url']);
        }
        else if ($_GET['action'] == "portfolio"){
            $downloadJSON = new DownloadJSON();
            echo $downloadJSON->login($_GET['url'], $_GET['username'], $_GET['password']);
        }
        else {
            echo json_encode("invalid request");
        }
    }
}
```

Yours Sincerely,
Larssy1

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` so you actually save the cookie sessions. However, within the next request you're just doing a `file_get_contents`, so that will probably ignore the set cookie.

Try to retreive the content from the API with CURL also.

Also, the API is probably private for a reason.

Comment: I've tried the CURLOTP_COOKIEFILE in an earlier stage, however, it doesn't safe the major problem regarding the fact that CURL is at this moment, redirecting the entire website towards the Social Club page.